# Create 'Season' column from 'Date'

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, date

I'm somewhat familiar with ArcGIS Desktop, but have no experience in Python. I have about 100 shapefiles which have an attribute table containing a date, but I need a column which contains a corresponding season.

To complicate things a little more, I do not want to define seasons the traditional way. Seasons are defined as follows: 
a.  Summer = June, July, August, September
b.  Fall = October, November
c.  Winter = December, January, February, March
d.  Spring = April, May

So far, I've been pasting and copying each attribute table into Excel, and using a function that looks like this: =CHOOSE(MONTH(J2),"Winter","Winter","Winter","Spring","Spring","Summer","Summer","Summer","Summer","Fall","Fall","Winter")

I'm sure there is a faster way to do things.

---

I recently added a 'MONTH' column using this script: Left( [GMT_DATE] , Len( [GMT_DATE] ) -8 )

---

I figured out how to generate a season column from a month column, but I am still unable to generate a season column directly from a date column. When I try I get "Winter" for everything.

[image]

Comment: i dont have time to write the code out, but in my head the pseudocode would be, if you have a field with the date, you can use split on "/" to get only the month,  then it would just be a simple if-then,  if month = 12,1,2,3 then season = "winter" , if month = 4,5, then season "spring" etc... I think there are some date functions that may do that automatically, but this will def work.

Comment: Is this in VB Script or Python? I've separated the month out into a separate column as you suggested, but can't seem to get the if-then statement to work. I just need help on syntax.

Comment: Please edit the question with your additional work.

Comment: Are you opposed to using R? I have a code that does exactly this already.

Comment: I'm not opposed, as long as I have good instructions.

Comment: In fact, since I have so many files, that would probably be preferable.

Comment: You say "can't seem to get the if-then statement to work. I just need help on syntax.", what does your code look like so far?

Comment: Dim [MONTH] As Text
If [MONTH] = 1 Then
  [SEASON] ="Winter"
ElseIf [MONTH] = 2 Then
  [SEASON] = "Winter"
...
etc.

But I'm very new to all of this. I could be way off base.

Comment: Added an R solution as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to use the code blocks. Here is an example of how it would work. *I tested it and it works*

Expression:

```
    getSeason(!MONTH!) #Or the name of your field for months
```

CodeBlock:

```
def getSeason(month):
    if (month == "DECEMBER" or month == "JANUARY" or month == "FEBRUARY" or month == "MARCH"):
       return "WINTER"
    elif(month == "APRIL" or month == "MAY"):
       return "SPRING"
    elif(month =="JUNE" or month=="JULY" or month == "AUGUST" or month == "SEPTEMBER"):
       return "SUMMER"
    else:
       return "FALL"
```

EDIT:
Of course you can use the date field

expression:

```
 getSeason(!DATE!)
```

CodeBlock

```
 def getSeason(date):
    month = int(date.split("/")[0])
    if (month > 11 or month <= 3):
       return "WINTER"
    elif (month == 4 or month == 5):
       return "SPRING"
    elif (month >=6 and month <= 9):
       return "SUMMER"
    else:
       return "FALL"
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.

Do you know if there is a way to do this without creating a 'MONTH' column.? i.e. Use a similar code, but use a date field with the format MM/DD/YYYY,

Comment: Sure, I edited the answer!

Comment: I appreciate the help Jonathan. For some reason I'm getting "WINTER" for every season when I try and use your second code using only the date field.

Comment: I am not completely sure but it may be a type issue,  i am not sure what format a date is in after you split it but I believe it is a string, so you would either need to make it int(month) >11 etc... or month == "11" etc... I could totally be wrong though, i am looking at this from my phone in the field.  maybe someone else can chime in.

Comment: That was all that was needed to fix it. Thanks Ed.

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry about that! I corrected the solution by adding int() in the getSeason function.

Answer (score 0):

In R using the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)

Birds<-read.csv("NearBirdsClean.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#date format 2010-08-21 YYYY-MM-DD
 #create dates variable for your column that contains dates 
dates <- Birds$Date_Found
#get the month of the date, create new column called month
Birds$month<-(month(dates, label=TRUE))
#new column called season
season <- Birds$season
#divide up your seasons by month
winter <-c("Dec","Jan", "Feb")
spring <- c("Apr", "May","Mar")
summer <- c("Jun", "Jul", "Aug")
fall <- c("Sep","Oct", "Nov")


#reformat to work with grep
winter <- paste(winter,collapse="|")
spring <- paste(spring,collapse="|")
summer<- paste(summer,collapse="|")
spring <- paste(spring,collapse="|")
fall <- paste(fall,collapse="|")
#populate the season field based on matching seasons (above) in the month field
season[grep(winter, Birds$month)] <- "winter"
season[grep(spring, Birds$month)] <- "spring"
season[grep(summer, Birds$month)] <- "summer"

season[grep(fall, nearBats$month)] <- "fall"
head(Birds)

  Date_Found month seasonB
1 2010-01-19   Jan  winter
2 2010-01-04   Jan  winter
3 2009-12-27   Dec  winter
4 2010-01-01   Jan  winter
5 2010-01-06   Jan  winter
6 2010-01-21   Jan  winter
```

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why? OP clarified in the comments they wanted an R solution...